# Allow keypress after 1 sec

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, keyup

I am animating div on keypress, but if i press up arrow 2x then my animation breaks,
Is there a way i can allow keypress only after 1 second?

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        $('.selected').animate({'top':'300px'},500);
        $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected')
                              .next('.section').animate({'top':'0'},500)
                              .addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your requirement as literally as possible:

```
var allowKeyPress = true;
$(document).keyup(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
    if (!allowKeyPress)
        return false;
    allowKeyPress = false;
    setTimeout(function() { allowKeyPress = true; }, 1000);

    $('.selected').animate({'top':'300px'},500);
    $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected').next('.section').animate({'top':'0'},500).addClass('selected');
    return false;    
  }    
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

That is, use a flag, `allowKeyPress` - on keyup test whether the flag is `false`, and if so stop immediately. Otherwise, continue, setting the flag to `false` and using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to schedule a function to run after one second to set the flag back to `true`, and of course running your animations.

Answer (score 1):

Check if elements are being animated before triggering further animations.:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
    if(!$('.selected').is(':animated')){

      $('.selected').animate({'top':'300px'},500);       
      $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected').next('.section').animate({'top':'0'},500).addClass('selected');
      return false;
    } 
  }    
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Fiddling with timing is messy business. This is much better. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 38 && !$('.selected').is(':animated')) { 
          $('.selected').animate({'top':'300px'},500);
          $('.section .selected').removeClass('selected')
                               .next('.section')
                               .animate({'top':'0px','position':'relative'},500)
                               .addClass('selected');
          return false;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: OP wants to prevent two keypresses within the same 1 second period, not delay _all_ keypresses by 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if any of the elements is animating and cancel the new animation.
So put the below code as the first line to your key-up function.

```
if($(".selected").is(":animated")) return;
```